# Установка ОС через BIOS

Tags: bios

Помогите разобраться с приоритетами настроек, чтобы установить ОС через BIOS. Пробовал ставить *Legacy mode*, поднял CD ROM наверх , но не сработало:

```
Boot mode:
[ Legacy, UEFI Hybrid, UEFI native]

UEFI Boot order:

[PCle/M.2 SSD Hard Drive, OS Boot manager,
  USB Hard Drive, Notebook EthernetIPV4,
  EthernetIPV6, Optical Disk drive
  Sd Card, Generic USB Device,
  Customized Boot
]

Legacy Boot Order:

[
  USB CD ROM
  PCle/M.2 SSD Drive
  Optical Disk Drive
  Notebook Hard Drive
  USB Hard Drive
  Notebook Ethernet
]
```

Comment: Лучше будет, если сообщите хотя бы, какую ОС ставите и на какую материнскую плату/ноутбук. И ставите с CD/DVD?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ставлю Ubuntu Gnome. На ноутбуке кажись только один привод, так что dvd. Ноутбук Hp, bios hawlett packard

Comment: А с чего вы ее ставите-то?

Comment: Мне кажется это мое личное дело

Comment: Под "с чего" - имелся в виду носитель - диск, флэшка и т.д. Вообще, обычно, если версия Ubuntu 13 и выше, спокойно ставите UEFI в настройках и ОС ставится без приключений. Иногда требуется отключить в BIOS Secure Boot. Прочтите в мануале к ноутбуку, по какой клавише после старта можно вызвать бут-меню, выставьте UEFI Hybrid, а затем нажав эту клавишу, выбирайте свой установочный DVD (желательно тоже в UEFI моде)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я попробую! Сейчас возник баг, мои кривые руки в настройках что-то поменяли , теперь дисковод , просто не читает  и даже откат биоса на заводские не помог. Решил посмотреть на ДУ, увидел , что слишком много канало I/O это нормально для дисковода ?